Can we have a [future-tense] tag?
We have tense and even conditional-mood, but not future-tense. Can we have one, please?
Abbiamo tense e anche conditional-mood, ma non future-tense. La potremmo avere, per favore?

Isn't it a bit too specific? How many existing questions would potentially use it?

@FedericoPoloni Not being used a lot is not a reason not to have a tag, as long as some questions use it, and it is well defined in scope. [tag:future-tense] seems perfectly fine to me as a concept

I would be happy to create the tag, but you can do so too (you only need 150 points of reputation on this site). Be careful that tags cannot exist "alone" without questions attached, so the only way to create a tag is to edit (or ask) a question. Do you have any questions in mind that could benefit from the tag future-tense?

Sarei felice di creare il tag, ma anche tu puoi farlo (c'è bisogno di soli 150 punti di reputazione su questo sito). Attenzione che i tag non possono esistere "soli" senza domande collegate, per cui l'unico modo di creare un tag è di modificare (o chiedere) una domanda. Hai qualche domanda in mente che potrebbe beneficiare del tag future-tense?

I've seen now your question and I have created the tag (and the synonym in Italian) just by editing it. For the next time: just write the name of the tag as if it existed, and when you submit the question it will pop into existence as if by magic :)
